# How would I open a site like I would in Expression Web but running on Linux?

Tags: webserver

In Expression Web, you can simply go to Site >> Open Site and connect to a specific server and updating your site from there, especially used in college. However, I know of NO current Linux alternative to Expression Web that with two clicks, can connect to a server by given URL so I can access the files and edit the code there. Are there any? Moreover, can I view my changes by one-click opening the code in a browser? I love Linux and I have been using it for a while but during the college year now I've had to use Windows because I didn't have time to do too much research.

Answer (score 1):

There is alot into that question . I belive you want to have access to a site folder and change/edit/add/update the contents/code of your site. If that is what you are asking for then you can use something like winscp . Its a utility that you download to your PC and connect to the server that hosts your app/website [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).